# How to uninstall glibc

Tags: glibc

I was trying to install and launch a Mathematica on a server, but it couldn't find glibc:

```
/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found
```

I installed a glibc-2.0 in my account, but I didn't install it correctly. I couldn't run almost any command after installing it. For example, when I ran `ls`, I got:

```
ls: error while loading shared libraries: __vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument
```

I need to uninstall it, but I failed to clean it by running `make clean`. I got this message:

```
Makeconfig:42: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

How can I uninstall it manually? Which files should I remove besides libc? Since a older version of glibc was already installed on the server, it's totally safe to remove the one in my account.

Comment: Why did you want to install which version of `glibc` on what kind of server? What makes you think it did not install correctly? What is the context of the error message? Your question is like »I replaced the cylinder head in my truck, but it went wrong. When I want to revert that, I hear a strange sound. What do I need to thrown away? Sorry that I don't know much about cars.« My recommendation: Don't touch anything and ask someone to take a look at the server.

Comment: @ Philippos OK, let me explain it in detail. First, I installed a Mathematica on the sever. But when I launch Mathematica, it couldn't find glibc (/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found). So I try to install a glibc-2.0 in my account. After installing it, I couldn't run almost any command. For example, when I run "ls", I got a message: "ls: error while loading shared libraries: __vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument".

Comment: Furthermore, since an older version of glibc was already installed on the sever, so it's totally safe to remove the one in my account.

Comment: If you have clarifications to your question, then please add these to the text of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glibc` is the GNU C Library project, which provides the core libraries for the GNU/Linux systems. It is installed by default on any system (even those with a minimal install) and cannot be uninstalled since it provides the APIs for all basic functioning of the OS.

You should uninstall any version of `glibc` you installed in your account, then ask a sysadmin to update `glibc` on the server, if possible.

To uninstall from your account, run `make uninstall`. If the makefile doesn't provide an "uninstall" target, you can run `make -n install`, which  will show you the steps that the software would take to install itself without doing anything (dry run). You can then try to manually reverse those steps.

Comment: Thanks. So which files should I remove?

Comment: To uninstall from your account, run `make uninstall`. If the makefile doesn't provide an "uninstall" target, you can run `make -n install`, which will show you the steps that the software would take to install itself without doing anything (dry run). You can then try to manually reverse those steps.